# Replace multiple bits in a short

Tags: java, binary, byte, bit, short

How can I replace multiple bits in a short in Java?

I'm working on a encryption algorithm where I need to do the following:
I got a short and need to apply a series of replacements of 4 bits.
Example: if the first 4 bits are `0010`, replace them with `0110`, if its `1111`, replace them with `1100` and so on, the same for the second 4 bits.

What is the best/fastest way to do this? At the moment I convert the short to a String and do it with String replacement but its obviously extremely slow and in my opinion the absolute wrong way.

Comment: What's the right way in your opinion? How did you try to implement it, and what problems did you run into? Show your code ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if you want help with your homework, you gotta make some effort yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit arithmetic, something like this:

```
short s = 191;
short first = (short) (s & 0x000F);
short second = (short) ((s >> 4) & 0x000F);
short third = (short) ((s >> 8) & 0x000F);
short fourth = (short) ((s >> 12) & 0x000F);

call_the_method_to_convert_each();

s = fourth;
s = ((short) ((s << 4) | third));
s = ((short) ((s << 4) | second));
s = ((short) ((s << 4) | first));
```

Comment: It worked exactly liked that, thanks!